# The Eigenstate Existence Problem in Dirac's book 'Principles of Quantum Mechanics'

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, eigenvalue, observables

In Chapter II p. 32 of Dirac's book *Principles of Quantum Mechanics*, Dirac explains that in general it is very difficult to know whether, for a given real linear operator, that any eigenvalues/eigenvectors exist and (if they do) how to find them.

He then goes on to state that a special tractable case can be found in the event that a real linear operator, $\xi$ can be expressed as the algebraic expression:

$$\phi(\xi) \equiv\xi^n  + a_1   \xi^{n-1}  + a_2 \xi^{n-2}  + ... + a_n  = 0\tag{17}$$

Where the $a_i$ are all numbers. He then factorises this as:

$$\phi(\xi) \equiv (\xi- c_1)(\xi- c_2)(\xi- c_3)...(\xi- c_n)\tag{18}$$

Where the $c_i$ are also numbers.

I'm unsure how this factorisation has been achieved. Since Dirac didn't explicitly state the difference between $\phi$($\xi$) and plain $\xi$, then I imagine that $\xi$ represents a given dynamical variable and $\phi$($\xi$) the corresponding operator. This may be incorrect however. This is the only step in the logic that I can't work out, I understand his subsequent arguments but this step is eluding me.

Comment: He factorizes suposing that, in the case that you act over a proper eigenvector, the operator behaves as a normal number, and since you have a polinomial equation, with real values, one can, thus, use the fundamental theorem of algebra do factorize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the equations, $\phi$ is the operator acting on the variable/state $\xi$. It is important to notice also that in the factorization the $a_i$ numbers are *real* and the $c_i$ are *complex*. This factorization comes just from the mathematical fact that for a polynomial equation of degree $n$, such as the first equation, there are $n$ complex roots.