# Dirac's Principles of QM the eigenstate existence problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, eigenvalue

In the second chapter (pp32-34) PAM states that should a real linear operator obey a certain expression (the characteristic equation, from what I understand) of degree $n$ then there are 2 statements that can be proved. In the book, they're denoted $\alpha$ and $\beta$. I'm having trouble understanding the $\beta$ part of the proof since in the $\alpha$ he utilized the argument that since $\chi_{r}(\xi)|p>$ cannot vanish for every ket because then we'd have to have $\xi $ satisfying an algebraic equation of degree $n-1$, which would contradict the assumption that the characteristic equation is the simplest one that $\xi $ satisfies. Now in the $\beta $ part, he introduces the expression $\sum_{r}\frac{\chi_r(\xi)}{\chi_{r}(c_{r})} -1 $ which vanishes for every eigenvalue of $\xi$ and then says the since the expression in only of degree $n-1$ in $\xi$, it must vanish identically. So my question is: doesn't it negate the argument on which the derivation is built, that it's the expression of degree $n$ which makes every ket $0$?

Comment: Hi icannotcan, note that inline math expressions must be enclosed in `$`'s, while display mode math expressions must be enclosed in `$$`'s.  I've added the required characters to your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Contradictory statements in Dirac's "Principles of Quantum Mechanics"?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/667859/)